# Java Bytecode: invokevirtual methodref on an objectref with a different class

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode, invokevirtual

I am currently looking into how Java bytecode works.
I created this simple test class:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

With `javap -c Main.class` I can get its bytecode:

```
class Main {
  Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #13                 // String Hello, World!
       5: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

The first instruction that should be executed (according to my understanding) should be the `getstatic` instruction in the `main` function. This leads to the `System` class and others like `Console` being loaded.

During the `<clinit>` method of `Console`:

```
static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // class java/io/Console
       2: invokevirtual #203                // Method java/lang/Class.desiredAssertionStatus:()Z
...
```

a `invokevirtual` method is executed to call the `desiredAssertionStatus` function on the class `Class`. One can already see a difference between this `invokevirtual` instruction and the one above: `javap` appends the class name before the method name because the function is found in the class `Class` and not in `Console`.

So finally my question is: What is going on here? According to the [JVM 19 specification for `invokevirtual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) the method should be invoked on the object that was on the stack. In this case `Console` but this class doesn't have the requested method nor is it a subclass of `Class`. What does the JVM intend to do here/how do JVM implementations like Hotspot go about doing this.
Do they just put the method onto the `Console` class for the duration of the instruction or somehow inject the class `Class` into `Console` or maybe there is something completely different going on here that I am missing?

Anyways thank you for taking your time to read my question!

I hope you have/had a wonderful day :)

I thought about doing the following things:

- Adding the method to the `Console` class for the duration of the instruction. This doesn't work because the method requires fields from the class `Class`.
- Actually just calling the method on an instance of `Class` which is created on the fly but I think these seems weird.
- This might be a very special case because I think that it has something to do with `Console` trying to interact with its `ClassLoader`. If this is a special case and there aren't many occurrences of this happening: Maybe the JVM just does some under the hood magic like assigning each class an instance of `Class` after loading which is then used for just this. Also seems weird to me.

Comment: `ldc` **l**oa**d**s a **c**onstant.

Comment: Adding more to first comment: What do you think that ldc #2 instruction does? I'll give you a hint: It's not pushing an instance of Console to the stack.

Comment: [ldc spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc) so its actually pushing a reference to `Class` onto the stack? If that is the case then I am very sorry. Typical case of not seeing the forest because of all the trees. I assumed it would push a reference to the class with the name at that index onto the stack but reading your comments I see now that it might be referring to the class `Class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> One can already see a difference between this `invokevirtual` instruction and the one above: `javap` appends the class name before the method name because the function is found in the class `Class` and not in `Console`.

but there is no difference in that regard. `javap` included the class name in both cases. In case of the `println` method, it’s the class `java/io/PrintStream`.

For ordinary Java code, the `ldc` instruction may load primitive values or objects of type `String` or `Class`. We can reproduce such cases with

```java
public class Main {
  static {
        Console.class.desiredAssertionStatus();
        "hello".toString();
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showBytecode();
    }
  
    private static void showBytecode() {
        ToolProvider.findFirst("javap")
            .ifPresent(p -> p.run(System.out, System.err, "-c", "Main"));
    }
  
    private Main() {}
}
```

###### [online example](https://tio.run/##dVBBasMwELz7FUInGxJ9wFBoC70VAumt9KBam2Rd2Wt21y6h@O2unLjFoVSHZZgdzQxb@8Fv6/AxTdh0xGrqRDgk90itUIQyW/O9YnTSoXshijumAQNwmWVd/x6xMlX0IubZY2u@MmNEvSZ2hte3eLqLzgUQZAj3IsCK1O6TvJe8KH/19gQxknVKe2Vsjz@7Mc0LWHKXoIEwmCal51f565vxfJRi1UBO9PlwVqgowF83xsEr3Njdflg5rS/gDtiGJ2TR3M536mzh8LBjEGg178z2znSO@9TrLAqNo143ZsHAvDF2W9k058vZ4r9a83auMGZjNk3f)

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #1                  // Method showBytecode:()V
       3: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #13                 // class java/io/Console
       2: invokevirtual #14                 // Method java/lang/Class.desiredAssertionStatus:()Z
       5: pop
       6: ldc           #15                 // String hello
       8: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/String.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      11: pop
      12: return
}
```

We can see that `javap` will always print the *actual value* after an `ldc` instruction, so in this example, “class java/io/Console” and “String hello”.

The `ldc` instruction can also load objects of other types, but there are no ordinary Java language equivalents to these use cases.

The `desiredAssertionStatus()` query is, by the way, typically used to implement the `assert` statement support, eg.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert "foo".length() == 3;
        showBytecode();
    }

    private static void showBytecode() {
        ToolProvider.findFirst("javap")
            .ifPresent(p -> p.run(System.out, System.err, "-c", "Main"));
    }

    private Main() {}
}
```

###### [gets compiled to](https://tio.run/##bU@xasMwEN31FYcmCWItGUM6dOhWCLRb6KBasnOubInT2SUUf7srE1MS6A13x7t3vPc6O9mqc1/Lgn2KxNAVwIyMweSE5j3GcKI4ofN0ECKNnwFrqIPNGV4tDvAjoNSGZ7ZcxhTRQV@u6o0Jh/b8AZbarDfyWuXfFzHZxChN8EPLF6XheIT94Y@TL/H7@cq@js4rfcNncdMjnCz7B8FH@p3WfQbT4OBekDIruSZNUhtsTuSzH1glqJ4gGRqL82tm35s48g623RPtQFa1LH3NLvX/ptbbamAWs1iWXw)

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main {
  static final boolean $assertionsDisabled;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #1                  // Field $assertionsDisabled:Z
       3: ifne          23
       6: ldc           #2                  // String foo
       8: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
      11: iconst_3
      12: if_icmpeq     23
      15: new           #4                  // class java/lang/AssertionError
      18: dup
      19: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":()V
      22: athrow
      23: invokestatic  #6                  // Method showBytecode:()V
      26: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #18                 // class Main
       2: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/lang/Class.desiredAssertionStatus:()Z
       5: ifne          12
       8: iconst_1
       9: goto          13
      12: iconst_0
      13: putstatic     #1                  // Field $assertionsDisabled:Z
      16: return
}
```